# How can I create a two dimensional array with index and with key in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a two dimensional array with index and with key in JavaScript, each row has the index and column has the key

```
myArray[0]=["S.No":"1", "Name":"abcd", "Age":"12"];
myArray[1]=["S.No":"2", "Name":"efgh", "Age":"15"];
myArray[2]=["S.No":"3", "Name":"ijkl", "Age":"20"];
```

So the output Should be

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    [S.No] => 1
    [Name] => abcd
    [Age] => 12
    )

[1] => Array
    (
    [S.No] => 2
    [Name] => efgh
    [Age] => 15
    )

[2] => Array
    (
    [S.No] => 2
    [Name] => ijkl
    [Age] => 20
    )
)
```

How to do this in JavaScript?

Want an array like this for php from javaScript.

Comment: give us an javascript example output, not an php?

Comment: It sounds like you want an array of objects, not a two dimensional array

Comment: Want an array like this for php from javaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create an array with keys, because this is not the way an array works. But you can nest an object (key-value-pair) into your array.

```
myArray[0] = {
    "S-No": 1, "Name" : "abcd", "Age": 12
};
myArray[1] = {
    "S-No": 2, "Name" : "efgh", "Age": 12
};
myArray[2] = {
    "S-No": 3, "Name" : "ijkl", "Age": 20
};
```

When you type `myArray[0]` JS will return the object `{"S-No": 2, "Name" : "efgh", "Age": 12 }`.

And you can access the object's properties easily, e.g.
`myArray[0].name` will return `abcd`.

Also you can iterate through the object's properties. Have a look at my code example.

```js
let myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = {
    "S-No": 1, "Name" : "abcd", "Age": 12
};
myArray[1] = {
    "S-No": 2, "Name" : "efgh", "Age": 12
};
myArray[2] = {
    "S-No": 3, "Name" : "ijkl", "Age": 20
};

// Acesss objects
console.log('>> 1');
console.log(myArray[0])


// Access object properties
console.log('>> 2');
console.log(myArray[0].Name);

// Iterate through object properties
console.log('>> 3');
let myObject = myArray[0];
for(let key in myObject){
    console.log('Key = ' + key + ' | Value = ' + myObject[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create multi dimensional arrays just like other languages. The difference is that you need to initialize a new array at index.

```
let a = [];
for ( let i=0; i<5; i++){
  // Created a new array on index of 1st dimension.
  a[ i ] = [];
  for ( let j=0; j < 2; j++ ) {
    // Here you can add elements to your 2nd dimension.
    a[i][j] = {'a':1};
    // As per your specific requirement, You can do it in following way
    a[i]['Name'] = 'Username';
  }
}
console.log ('a ', a);
console.log('User name', a[0]['Name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have arrays with named indexes so you can't do something like myArray[0]['Name'] You could have a two dimensional array, an array with arrays as its entries, but they would be accessed for example by myArray[0][1]

Luckily in JavaScript there is the concept of object (and in fact arrays are special types of object). You can have an array of objects and it looks as though that is what you want from what you have given which is:

```
myArray[0]=["S.No":"1", "Name":"abcd", "Age":"12"];
myArray[1]=["S.No":"2", "Name":"efgh", "Age":"15"];
myArray[2]=["S.No":"2", "Name":"ijkl", "Age":"20"];
```

You can define an object like this
obj={
'S_No': '12',
'Name': 'abcd',
'Age': '20'
}

In your case you could do:

```html
<script>
var myArray=[];
myArray[0]={'S_No': '1','Name': 'abcd','Age': '12'};

console.log(myArray);
console.log(myArray[0].Name);
console.log(myArray[0].S_No);
</script>
```

Note that you cannot have . in S.No so I have replaced it with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

The basic code to create such array:

```
var obj=[];
var array={};
//loop the resulted data OR hard code and push it
for(loop the data){
array.sno = "1"; //data.sno
array.Name = "abcd"; //data.Name
array.Age = "12"; //data.Age
obj.push(array);
}
```

when you try console.log(obj[0]) it will print the 0th element